# TypeError: web3.eth.sendTransaction(...).then is not a function

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, testrpc

I was trying to transfer some ether using ganache desktop application in **nodejs**. It was properly working but suddenly an error occurred.

```
var s = 1;

try{
 web3.eth.sendTransaction({
 from: '0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57',
 to:'0x821aea9a577a9b44299b9c15c88cf3087f3b5544',
 value: web3.toWei(s.toString(), "ether")

}).then(function(receipt) {
    console.log(receipt);
    res.json({success: true});

}).catch(function(e){
console.log('error occured');
console.log(e);
res.json({success: false });
});
```

If **.then()** and **.catch()** is removed, ether is transferred.

Comment: if you are not using promises. Try using fallback fuctions

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh I think you mean "callback" functions.

Comment: What version of web3.js are you using? 0.2x.0 doesn't support promises, but 1.0.0-beta.x does.

Comment: I'm using 0.18.4 version and it was working perfectly..suddenly today this error showed up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a callback. Kindly read the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction).

```
var handleReceipt = (error, receipt) => {
  if (error) console.error(error);
  else {
    console.log(receipt);
    res.json(receipt);
  }
}

web3.eth.sendTransaction({
 from: '0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57',
 to:'0x821aea9a577a9b44299b9c15c88cf3087f3b5544',
 value: web3.toWei(s.toString(), "ether")
}, handleReceipt);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is straight from the documentation:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: '0x123...', data: '0x432...'})
.once('sending', function(payload){ ... })
.once('sent', function(payload){ ... })
.once('transactionHash', function(hash){ ... })
.once('receipt', function(receipt){ ... })
.on('confirmation', function(confNumber, receipt, latestBlockHash){ ... })
.on('error', function(error){ ... })
.then(function(receipt){
    // will be fired once the receipt is mined
}); and it does not recognize .once, .on, or.then
or.catch
```

Comment: Please, reformat your answer, use code snippets so others can better understand what you were trying to say.